# How to use group by and also sum on a database record using linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have a table structure that looks that this

```
 listed_companyid         numberof_units           userid
-----------------     -----------------        ----------------
       2                     4                        2
       2                     2                        2   
       1                     6                        2
       5                     3                        3
```

For `userid = 2` i want

```
total_unit = 12 

// Additionally

listed_companyid = 2, total = 6
listed_companyid = 1, total = 6
```

**Code**

```
var  listed = dbContext.listedCompanies.ToList();
var stock = dbContext.stocks.Where(m=>m.userid == 2).ToList();
var result = (from s in stock
              join l in listed on s.listed_companyid equals l.id group s  by new { s.listed_companyid } into g select new
              {
                  g.Key,
                  total_unit = g.Sum(s => s.numberof_units)
              });
```

Comment: That sounds like 2 different queries. You've already materialized the data by using toList(), might as well just do 2 queries to get the appropriate data.

Comment: Trying to avoid doing two queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project a nested `GroupBy`

**Given**

```
public class Something
{
     public int listed_companyid { get; set; }
     public int numberof_units { get; set; }
     public int userid { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample App**

```
var list = new List<Something>
           {
              new Something() { listed_companyid = 2, numberof_units = 4, userid = 2 },
              new Something() { listed_companyid = 2, numberof_units = 2, userid = 2 },
              new Something() { listed_companyid = 1, numberof_units = 6, userid = 2 },
              new Something() { listed_companyid = 5, numberof_units = 3, userid = 3 },   
           };

var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.userid)
                  .Select(x => new 
                               {
                                  userId = x.Key,
                                  total_unit = x.Sum(y => y.numberof_units),
                                  sub = x.GroupBy(y => y.listed_companyid)
                                         .Select(y => new
                                                      {
                                                         listed_companyid = y.Key,
                                                         total = y.Sum(z => z.numberof_units)
                                                      })
                               });

foreach (var result in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine("userId : " + result.userId + ", total_unit  : " + result.total_unit);

   foreach (var sub in result.sub)
       Console.WriteLine(" - listed_companyid : " + sub.listed_companyid + ", total : " + sub.total);
}
```

**Output**

```
userId : 2, total_unit : 12
 - listed_companyid : 2, total : 6
 - listed_companyid : 1, total : 6
userId : 3, total_unit  : 3
 - listed_companyid : 5, total : 3
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/xXALSq)

**Note** : Convert to *Query Syntax*, and `IQueryable` as desired